# Should the *the* be used with Honorable? and Is the "t" capitalized in "the Honorable"?

Tags: articles, word-usage, phrase-choice

I remember some rule that tied using *the* with Honorable in *the Honorable.*

Is there a rule about using **the** with the abbreviated form of Honorable?

Should the **the** be used with Honorable?

Comment: Could you add some examples so we can understand the usage you are looking for? The word "Honorable" by itself is not enough.

Comment: If you're referring to the title (prefix) then you will still need to narrow it down to which use of that prefix you are asking about.

Comment: *Honorable* and *Hon,* like *Reverend,* are not always preceded by *the,* at least in the US. I don't know if there are rules or conventions about it. "On this the 16th day of May, 1983, comes the State of Alabama by its District Attorney, Honorable Michael L. Murphy, also comes the defendant, Donald Lee Silver . . . ." http://law.justia.com/cases/alabama/court-of-appeals-criminal/1983/448-so-2d-425-0.html

Comment: At least somewhere, sometimes, a *the* with honorifics signifies rank-related meaning: '..."Your Highness" and "Your Royal Highness"; between "Princess Margaret" and "The Princess Margaret". All of these are correct, but apply to people of subtly different rank.'  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, one [source](http://www.formsofaddress.info/Honorable.html) says, *the* is always used with *Honorable*.

*The Honorable (name)* is the correct form of address.

This [source](http://www.formsofaddress.info/Honorables.html#146) also says *the* is not capitalized unless it is the first word in a line or sentence.